# Compute $[\Lambda,\ \bar{\Lambda}]$

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, several-complex-variables

I have a problem:

> We denote by $[X,\ Y]$ **the commutator** of $X$ and $Y$ defined by
>   $$[X,\ Y]f(p)=X(Yf)(p)-Y(Xf)(p), \tag{1}$$
>   for any smooth function $f$ defined on a hypersurface $M$.
>
> The form of **the CR vector fields** given in $(2)$:
>   $$\Lambda =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} -i\frac{\phi_{\bar{z}}}{1+i\phi_s} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}.\tag{2}$$ 
>   Show that
>
> $$\begin{align*}[\Lambda,\ \bar{\Lambda}]
> &=i\dfrac{\phi_{z \overline{z}}}{1-i\phi_s}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}+i\dfrac{\phi_{\overline{z}{z}}}{1+i\phi_s}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}+i\phi_{z}\left ( \dfrac{1}{1-i\phi_s} \right )_{\overline{z}}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s} \\ 
> &\quad +i\phi_{\overline{z}}\left ( \dfrac{1}{1+i\phi_s} \right )_{{z}}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}-i\left (\dfrac{\phi_{\overline{z}}}{1+i\phi_s}  \right )\left (\dfrac{\phi_{{z}}}{1-i\phi_s}  \right )_{s}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s} \\
> &\quad +i\left ( \dfrac{\phi_{{z}}}{1-i\phi_s} \right )\left ( i\dfrac{\phi_{\overline{z}}}{1+i\phi_s} \right )_s\dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}. \end{align*}$$?????
>
> with $\phi_{\bar z}=\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z},\ \phi_{s}=\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial s} $.

---

What I've tried:

I think that we need to use **Wirtinger derivatives**, so I write: 
$$\begin{align*}[\Lambda,\ \bar{\Lambda}]&=[\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} -i\frac{\phi_{\bar{z}}}{1+i\phi_s} \frac{\partial}{\partial s},\  \overline{\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} -i\frac{\phi_{\bar{z}}}{1+i\phi_s} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}}]\\
&=[\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} -i\frac{\phi_{\bar{z}}}{1+i\phi_s} \frac{\partial}{\partial s},\ \frac{\partial}{\partial {z}} +i\frac{\bar{\phi}_{z}}{1-i\bar{\phi}_{\bar s}} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} ]
\end{align*}$$
Is it correct?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter: Why do you downvote me?